# Association properties on Entity not loaded for server-side validation

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Consider the following situation. I have an Entity named *ProductSupplier* that is a Presentation Model. It is created by doing an inner join of *Products* and *Suppliers*, and creating a new projection from a Linq statement. The *ProductSupplier* projection also creates a list of *PartType* objects, which is also a Presentation Model.

```
public partial class ProductSupplier
{
    private IEnumerable<PartType> _partTypes;

    [Key]
    public int ProductSupplierKey { get; set }

    [Include]
    [Association("ProductSupplier_PartType", "ProductSupplierKey", "ProductSupplierKey")]
    public IEnumerable<PartType> PartTypes
    {
        get { return _partTypes ?? (_partTypes = new List<PartType>()); } 
        set { if (value != null) _partTypes = value; }
    }
}

public partial class PartType
{
    [Key]
    public int PartTypeKey { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int ProductSupplierKey { get; set; }

    public int PartQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a validation that is **no *ProductSupplier* can be have more than 10 separate parts**. This means that all PartQuantities for all *PartTypes* that belong to a *ProductSupplier* should be summed, and the total cannot exceed 10.

For this, I created a custom validator:

```
public static ValidationResult ValidatePartTotals(ProductSupplier productSupplier, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (productSupplier.PartTypes.Sum(p => p.PartQuantity) > 10)
        return new ValidationResult("Must be less than 10 parts total.");

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

This works fine when validation is called from the client-side. The problem I'm having is that when the validator is run from the server-side, the IEnumerable is always empty.

I have tried adding [RoundTripOriginal] to the PartQuantity, and to various other properties, such as all the Key fields, but it still is an empty list when done on the server side.

How can I access these PartType objects when validation is run on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't have any guarantees as to the state of the object graph when it gets to you on the server. RIA optimizes things so you'll only see modified entities. One solution would be to use composition. It will make sure the whole graph is passed around, but it has other effects that may not be what you want. Another option would be to hydrate the graph in your update method, then perform validation, and throw a ValidationException as necessary.

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer. I just want to make it clear for anyone searching this answer: attributing your property with [Composition] instead of [Association] will force the entire object graph to be passed back to the service.